# How do I evaluate $\int_{\Gamma_{R}}\frac{1}{(z^{2}+64)(z^{2}+4)}\hspace{0.2em}dz$ using the residue theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have the integral $$\int_{\Gamma_{R}}\frac{1}{(z^{2}+64)(z^{2}+4)}\hspace{0.2em}dz$$ where $\Gamma_{R} = [-R,R] \cup \Gamma_{R}^{+}$, with $\Gamma_{R}^{+} := \gamma_{0,R}\vert_{[0,\pi]}(t) =  R(\cos{t} + i\sin{t})$, for $R>8$. $[-R,R]$ is a straight-line segment path and $\Gamma_{R}^{+}$ is a semi-circular path.

I found the residues at the poles $z = \pm 8i, \pm 2i$, but then I don't really know how to proceed. I stated that since it's a piece-wise regular path then we have that $$\int_{\Gamma_{R}}\frac{1}{(z^{2}+64)(z^{2}+4)}\hspace{0.2em}dz = \int_{[-R,R]}\frac{1}{(z^{2}+64)(z^{2}+4)}\hspace{0.2em}dz + \int_{\Gamma_{R}^{+}}\frac{1}{(z^{2}+64)(z^{2}+4)}\hspace{0.2em}dz.$$ Then, I estimated the path integral by fixing $\lvert z \rvert = R > 8$ $$\Bigg\lvert \int_{\gamma\vert_{[0,\pi]}} f(z) \hspace{0.2em}dz \Bigg\rvert \leq \Bigg(\sup_{t\in [0,\pi]}\lvert f(\gamma(t))\rvert\Bigg)\times \ell(\gamma\vert_{[0,\pi]}) \leq \frac{1}{R^{4}}\cdot \pi R = \frac{\pi}{R^{3}}$$which resulted in the integral being $$\int_{\Gamma_{R}^{+}}\frac{1}{(z^{2}+64)(z^{2}+4)}\hspace{0.2em}dz = 0$$for large $R$.

I don't know if I did it right, but now I'm stuck, have no idea how to apply the residue theorem on the linear path and don't really know what I'm doing.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: your integral is $2i\pi(Res_{z=2i}(f)+Res_{z=8i}(f))$.

Comment: @Surb This may be a dumb question but why do we omit $-8i$ and $-2i$?

Comment: Because they are not in $\Gamma _R$.

Comment: Please do not delete your question immediately after receiving an answer. This is rude to the person who took the time to answer your question, and rude to potential future readers who might benefit from the question and answer pair.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z)=\frac1{(z^2+64)(z^2+4)}$, then$$\operatorname{res}_{z=2i}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=-\frac i{240}\quad\text{and}\quad\operatorname{res}_{z=8i}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=\frac i{960},$$and therefore$$\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\left(-\frac i{240}+\frac i{960}\right)=\frac\pi{160}.$$